# How to increase spacing between grouped bars

Tags: python, matplotlib, bar-chart

I have a large dataset, and I have multiple groups, but increasing the bar width can not help because the group doesn't have the same size. You can see that there is no space between `11` and `12`, and I need every group to be plotted separately.

Here is an example to show my problem.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

bar_width = 0.25

r = [8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
r1 = [(x) for x in r]
bars1 = [10,20, 40, 60, 80]

r = [1, 2, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
r2 = [(x + bar_width) for x in r]

bars2 = [5, 10,15, 20, 40, 60, 80]

bars3 = [ 12,23, 70, 94]
r = [4, 5,  11, 14]
r3 = [(x + bar_width * 2) for x in r]



bars4 = [ 60,120, 193]
r = [ 10,  11, 14]
r4 = [(x + bar_width * 3) for x in r]


r = [1, 2,3,4,5,6,7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
r5 = [(x + bar_width * 4) for x in r]
bars5 = [3,5,23,14, 10, 20, 45,40,56, 60, 80,99]

plt.bar(r1, bars1, width=bar_width, align='center')
plt.bar(r2, bars2, width=bar_width, align='center')
plt.bar(r3, bars3, width=bar_width, align='center')
plt.bar(r4, bars4, width=bar_width, align='center')
plt.bar(r5, bars5, width=bar_width, align='center')
plt.legend(
    ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'))

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Switch to horizontal bars and make the plot longer. Use a log scale if some bars are not visible because they are short compared to longer bars. I don't recommend stacked bars: _One major flaw of Stacked Bar Graphs is that they become harder to read the more segments each bar has. Also comparing each segment to each other is difficult, as they're not aligned on a common baseline._

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your application, instead of bars next to each other, stacked bars could be a solution.

Instead of calculating positions and widths, pandas plotting could be easier.

Here is an example:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

r1 = [8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
bars1 = [10, 20, 40, 60, 80]

r2 = [1, 2, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
bars2 = [5, 10, 15, 20, 40, 60, 80]

r3 = [4, 5, 11, 14]
bars3 = [12, 23, 70, 94]

r4 = [10, 11, 14]
bars4 = [60, 120, 193]

r5 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
bars5 = [3, 5, 23, 14, 10, 20, 45, 40, 56, 60, 80, 99]

rs = r1 + r2 + r3 + r4 + r5
heights = bars1 + bars2 + bars3 + bars4 + bars5
names = ['a'] * len(bars1) + ['b'] * len(bars2) + ['c'] * len(bars3) + ['d'] * len(bars4) + ['e'] * len(bars5)

df = pd.DataFrame({'r': rs,
                   'height': heights,
                   'name': names})
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(ncols=2, figsize=(15, 4))
for ax in (ax1, ax2):
    df.pivot(index='r', columns='name', values='height').plot.bar(stacked=(ax == ax2), rot=0, ax=ax)
ax1.set_title('dodged bars')
ax2.set_title('stacked bars')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: dodged vs stacked bar plot]

The same dataframe can also help if you want to write custom code, for example with dodged bars leaving out the empty ones:

```py
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
colors = {'a': 'C0', 'b': 'C1', 'c': 'C2', 'd': 'C3', 'e': 'C44'}
tick_pos = []
tick_r = []
name_list = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
pos = 0
for r in range(df['r'].min(), df['r'].max() + 1):
    start_pos = pos
    for name in name_list:
        row = df[(df['r'] == r) & (df['name'] == name)]
        if len(row) != 0:
            ax.bar(pos, row['height'], color=colors[name], width=1)
            pos += 1
    end_pos = pos
    if start_pos != end_pos:
        tick_pos.append((start_pos + end_pos - 1) / 2)
        tick_r.append(r)
        pos += 0.3 # this is the gap between the groups
ax.set_xticks(tick_pos)
ax.set_xticklabels(tick_r)
ax.legend(handles=[plt.Rectangle((0, 0), 0, 0, color=colors[n]) for n in name_list], labels=name_list)
ax.margins(x=0.01)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: custom bars leaving out empty spots]